# WordPress Betheme: Unkown subheader image of a child page

Tags: child-pages, images

I want to get the URL of the Muffin Betheme subheader image of a child page, in the parent one, for each of its children.

Thus, I go through the children, then I *try* to get the subheader image for each child and I display it.

```
foreach (get_page_children(get_the_ID(), (new WP_Query())->query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'post_status' => 'publish'))) as $child) {

    $html_to_display .= '<a href="' . get_permalink($child) . '"><img src="' . wp_get_attachment_image_src($child->ID, 'large') . '" />' . get_the_title($child) . '</a>';

}
```

However, `wp_get_attachment_image_src($child->ID, 'large')` returns:

> Unknown

I checked out the subheader image of this child, and the upload actually exists.

## Question

How could I display this subheader image correctly?

## Metaquestion

What tags would you recommend me to use in this SO question?

Answer (score 0):

Use get_the_post_thumbnail_url() instead of wp_get_attachment_image_src()

wp_get_attachment_image_src(): this function takes attachment id as first parameter

Comment: I replaced the line with: `$html_to_display .= '<a href="' . get_permalink($child) . '"><img src="' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url($child, 'large') . '" />' . get_the_title($child) . '</a>';`. Now it shows *false* instead of *unkown*

Comment: Have you attach image to child page? Function returns false  if no URL is available

Comment: Yes, I attached a subheader image (field *subheader image*). Are you speaking about this image or the one attached to any page, indpendently of using the Muffin Betheme?